# Adobe Sign Liquid Mode - Display HTML DIV based on Drop Down Selection

Tags: html, adobe-sign

We are using Adobe Sign Liquid Mode.
This is HTML based with Adobe Sign Text Tags inserted throughout.

I would like to display a DIV based upon the selection from a specific text tag drop down.

```
{{*eaRegFee_es_:signer1:dropdown(options="Credit Card,Electronic Check,Check - Mailed In,Money Order - Mailed In,Cash"):dimension(width=70mm, height=6mm)}}
```

If Credit Card, display the following:

```
<div><p>Call-in Credit Card # for Registration Fee Payment</p></div>
```

If Check - Mailed In or Money Order - Mailed In, display the following:

```
<div><p>Please send your check or money order to the address below within twenty-four hours.<br>Company Name<br>123 State Street<br>Anytown,ST. 11111</p></div>
```

If none of the above are selected, do not display anything.

Thank you!